# Ortographic Camera Aspect Ration on Resize

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

Is there anyway to setup an ortographic camera in THREE.JS such that:

1)It mantains a constant aspect ratio. Even when I aply a resize to the window. This aspect ratio whould be constant throughout, and not related to the window dimensions and aspect ratio, and avoid distortion.

2)The scene is always completely visible, no matter the size of the window.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand 1). If you want to avoid distortions, you have to adapt the projection to the window. Could you elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: I already do that but I want to make it such that no matter how small I resize the window, without distorting the scene, the whole scene is visible, and have been stumped on this problem for days.

Comment: Is your scene static or dynamic? Do you know the extents?

Comment: The scene is dynamic, I can move objects in and out of the scene, but I have to make sure that some of the objects in it are always visible when I resize the window.

Comment: So the initial position of the objects is what matters and It must always contain the objects in their initial position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have your current camera and you want to make sure that your entire scene fits in its view. The variables that you can change in an `OrthographicCamera` are `left, right, top, bottom, near, far`. You usually want to make sure that `left = -right` and `top = -bottom`. And you need to make sure that the ratio is equal to the aspect ratio of the window. Thus, all you can change is essentially a single scale value.

What we are going to do to determine this is the following: We take all the points in our scene and transform them into camera space. Then, the minimum and maximum of x, y, and z, respectively, give us the minimum bounds for the camera. And then we just need to make sure that the aspect ratio is correct.

Now, doing this for all points is usually too computationally heavy. Instead, we could approximate our scene with a bounding sphere of radius `r` centered at `c`. You can either calculate those once at the beginning of your application or save them with the scene. And then, instead of making sure that the scene fits in the view, we make sure that the entire bounding sphere fits in the view.

Doing this for an orthographic camera is actually pretty simple. We just need to transform the center of the sphere into camera coordinates:

```
var cInCameraSpace = new THREE.Vector3(); //do this once at initialization

//transform sphere center to camera space
cInCameraSpace.copy(c);
cInCameraSpace.applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorldInverse)
```

And then we can find the bounds:

```
var halfWidth = Math.abs(cInCameraSpace.x) + r;
var halfHeight = Math.abs(cInCameraSpace.y) + r;
camera.near = -cInCameraSpace.z - r;
camera.far = -cInCameraSpace.z + r;
```

Now, lets make sure that we preserve aspect ratio. I assume that we already know the window's aspect ratio as `windowAspect`.

```
if(halfWidth / halfHeight > windowAspect) {
    camera.right = halfWidth;
    camera.top = halfWidth / windowAspect;
} else {
    camera.top = halfHeight;
    camera.right = halfHeight * windowAspect;
}
camera.bottom = -camera.top;
camera.left = -camera.right;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I understood it, I'm just not sure how I would go about getting the bounding sphere, and all the methods I found seem pretty complicated, can you help with that as well?

Comment: That depends a lot on your scene. Maybe you just know an approximate bounding sphere? If not, then what I do is usually just an approximation because we don't need a super accurate sphere. So I first calculate the axis-aligned bounding box (just take the min and max of all points) and then calculate the bounding sphere of that box (same center, radius is half of the diagonal length).

Comment: On the other hand, you could also make the camera adjustment based on the bounding box. Becomes a bit more work but nothing too complicated (and might get you a tighter view).

Comment: Hi, I implemented it just like you said, but it distorts the scene, anyway to have this happen without causing distortion?

Comment: hi, nevermind, forgot to updateProjectionMatrix, it's working, thank you very much!